# line break in javascript \n is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to do a line break in javascript with angular using scope so it displays in my front end using ionic. But it's not working. Is there another way to line break this.

```
$scope.pick= [
{
 name:"Fear",
 line:"\n\u2022 Do what you are afraid of doing...\n over and over."
}]
```

html

```
  <div class="list">
 <div class="item item-input item-select">
  <div class="input-label">

   </div>

  <select ng-model="tab" ng-init="tab=pick[0]" ng-options="tab.name for tab in pick"></select>
  </div>

 <div class="list list-inset">
 <div class="item">

<input type="text" ng-model="tab.line" id="displaycard">


<input type="text" ng-model="tab.line2" id="displaycard">

<input type="text" ng-model="tab.line3" id="displaycard">

</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Tried

```
    var somebreak = '<br />' + '\u2022 Do what you are afraid of doing...' + 
     '<br />'+ 'over and over.'

      $scope.pick= [{
      {
       name:"Fear",
       line: somebreak,
       }]
```

And Tried

```
     line:"<br/>\u2022 Do what you are afraid of doing...<br/> over and over.",
```

it still spits out this. 
 [image]

Comment: Use `<br />` to add line break in HTML page.

Comment: where? I don't understand if i put <br /> beside the input type

Comment: Where is the text supposed to be output? By the way, the HTML shown is invalid because you have repeated `id` values.

Comment: I am outputting these strings by calling them when the user is selecting the  tabs, so it spits out that specific string which are 3 lines.

Comment: `<br>` damnit, not `<br />` and anyway it's obvious the content is not considered html since we clearly see it's not parsed

Comment: maybe you want to give a shot to bindHTML: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Answer (score 0):

Use `<br/>`:

```
$scope.pick= [
{
 name:"Fear",
 line:"<br/>\u2022 Do what you are afraid of doing...<br/> over and over."
}]
```

Use `ng-bind-html`

A quick example, not by me: http://plnkr.co/edit/CO5WUCgBnOEJrVoKKrEE?p=preview

Comment: Still spits out <br/> •Do what you are afraid of doing...<br/> over and over."

Answer (score 0):

Assign the string value as mentioned below and use the variable in your array to keep it clean

```
var someVar = '<br />' + '\u2022 Do what you are afraid of doing...' + '<br />'+ 'over and over.'

$scope.pick= [ {  
name:"Fear", 
line:someVar }]
```

Comment: *"to keep it clean"* - Why does that keep it clean? Why are you concatenating several separate strings together?

Answer (score 0):

```
  var somebreak = "<br>"+"\u2022 Do what you are afraid of doing..."+"
  <br>"+"over and over."

  $scope.pick= [{

       name:"Fear",
       line: somebreak

  }]
```

Comment: Can you give some explanation for your answer?

Comment: i used <br> instead of <br/>. i have tested also. its working